# Python : Run a python script from another python script and get a variable from the first script

Tags: python

```
import json
import random
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import time

# run SCRIPT1 (SCRIPT1.py)

exec(open(SCRIPT1.py).read())


# Run request using 1 variable from SCRIPT1 
# Start Browser
mla_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:35000/api/v1/profile/start?profileId=' + profile_id
resp = requests.get(mla_url)
jsoni = resp.json()
```

The variable **profile_id** should be extracted from the script runned at the beginning (SCRIPT1)
How can i get that value in my current script ?

SCRIPT1 contains the variable like this :

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

profile_id = (response.text)
```

I tried :

```
z = script1

exec("from " + z + " import script1")
profile_id = myfunct()
```

It's working ! But the script1() runs twice. I want it to run only once

Comment: can you make the script one into a function?

Comment: the issue is that the way I choose script1 is randomly from a folder ( that contains lots of script1). All of them have the same variable at the end "profile_id ". So I can't includ it in my script because it's not static

Comment: could they all have a function?

Comment: yes @Mahrkeenerh ( Btw function mean def script1(): right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your scripts structure to look like this:

script01 ...

```
def your_func():

    # do stuff
    return profile_id
```

Now in your main file, you can do this:

```
exec("from " + filename + " import your_func")
profile_id = your_func()
```

Comment: I tried it i got SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what line was causing the issue?

Comment: I tried : exec("from " + z + " import script1")
profile_id = script1()
 where z is my python name, it works but it executed twice, i want it to execute only once

Comment: it doesn't work. `filename` is supposed to be the other file - script1, and after `import` you are supposed to specify the function you use inside your script1

Comment: This is what i did, it worked but it executed twice, it execute in the first line exec(...) and in the second line profile_id = your_func()

Comment: Can i replace exec in the first line ? and still make it work ? Like first line just import without execute

Comment: no, you need the exec. My guess is, that you also included the brackects after the function? Check out my example - no brackets to use the function the first time.